# Javascript making text bold?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use javascript to make text bold. I have searched the net and it seems that I can do a document.write() after I made my string bold. Isn't there any way to perform this without opening any new page (in the same html text area)?

```
function bold()
{
   document.write(selectedText.bold());
}
```

**Edit:** I am implementing an Text Editor and I am using a HTML TextArea, and I am trying to add all the functionality such as bold, italic, etc. I want to be able to select part of the text written and make it bold.

Comment: You may be better off using a [Javascript WYSIWYG Editor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) than re-inventing the wheel... (Ultimately there's probably more to this, including getting the user's selection in the edit box before bolding/italicing/etc.)

Comment: I am just trying to learn, nothing more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// method 1: direct write out something with bold tags
document.write('<b>My Bold Text</b>');

// method 2: add an element styled to be bold
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = 'My Bold Text';
span.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(span);

// method 3: add an element classed to be bold
// add style sheet first:
//   <style type="text/css">.bold { font-weight: bold; }</style>
// then the jS:
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = 'createElement.className - My Bold Text';
span.className = 'bold';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(span);
```

Something like that? Otherwise, please be more specific with your question.

Comment: i have edited my post, what if i am making the text bold inside an HTML Text Area ?

Comment: @yahyakh: `<textarea>` can only be uniformly styled (e.g. all bold, all italic, all normal, etc.). If you're looking to make it simulate something like wordpad or MS word, you need to switch to (or mimic) some form  of WYSIWYG editor which uses div overlays and a healthy amount of code to get working.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to set an existing element to bold? If this is the case, set `font-width` CSS property to `bold`. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("myTextId").style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

or, if you are using jQuery,

```
$('#myTextId').css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Update: HTML `<textarea>` tag does not support separate styling of different parts of its content; you can't make a rich text editor this way.

Comment: The OP never specified that they were using jQuery.

Comment: Well then, if you are using PHP use this: `<?= "<b>My bold text</b>"; ?>` (See how mentioning something else doesn't necessarily prove useful in specific contexts?)

Comment: OP wants to manipulate the DOM via javascript. Is the assumption that he may consider using a javascript DOM manipulation library to do so such a stretch?

Comment: @socha23 I think what others are telling you is that it is ok if you want to suggest to use a different library. However, your solution only had that one suggestion that may not help. Generally, I advice putting the right answer, in this case only java script, and then at the bottom say hey by the way you could be using jquery and make it a one liner. Only providing the jQuery solution is making too much of an assumption.